# EV3 Rapt3r's head cable interfering with slithering

Tags: ev3

My Rapt3r is working great, except that the cable that goes from the head to the "Intelligent Brick" physically interferes with the slithering on the side on which it is plugged (port 4).

Physically interfering in the sense that the cable being somewhat stiff prevents the motor from turning all the way on that side.

If I unplug the cable the slithering is much more balanced between the two sides. Is there a better way to thread that cable than what is shown in the instructions?

Answer (score -2):

That's bad. Try to unplug and plug fast and see what happens. Or try to connect the cable on the port that is beside, and then, connect it to its port. I hope that works.

Comment: Sorry, it is not a connection issue -- it is the cable itself physically preventing the motor from turning (I added some wording to the question to try to clarify).